# How to locate rejected index enteries

Tags: indexing

Some of my index entries are being rejected for some reason. How do I determine which index entries were rejected?

For instance if I uncomment the `\def` at the top of the MWE below I see the message in the console. All this does is switch from suing `\tiny` to `\small`.  Not sure why one would be ok but the other.

> Scanning input file TestIndex.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 10 rejected)

I searched for the word `rejected` in `imakeidx.sty` but that word is not in that file, so not sure where this message is coming from.

The above is just one cause of the entries being rejected. I need to know what are some of the other causes as I have some rejected without using `\small`.

### References:

- This is a follow up to [Index hyperlinks to open a PDF file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51601/index-hyperlinks-to-open-a-pdf-file/).

### Code:

```
%\def\UseSmallInIndex{}%

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}% database
\usepackage{imakeidx}% indexing
\usepackage{hyperref}% For cross references
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\makeindex

% ---------- Process Each Word:
%
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/how-do-i-split-a-string
\makeatletter
\def\ProcessEachWord#1{%
    \begingroup%
    \edef\@tempa{#1\space}%
    \gdef\@tempb{#1}%
    \expandafter\endgroup%
    \expandafter\ReadWords\@tempa\relax%
}%
\def\ReadWords#1 #2\relax{%
      \ProcessWord[\@tempb]{#1}%  #1 = substr, #2 = rest of string
      \begingroup%
      \ifx\relax#2\relax% is #2 empty?
         \def\next{\endgroup\EndProcessWords}% your own end-macro if required
      \else%
         \def\next{\endgroup\ReadWords#2\relax}%
      \fi%
      \next%
}%
\makeatother
% ---------- 


\newcommand{\ProcessWord}[2][]{%
    \ifdefined\UseSmallInIndex%
        \index{#2!#1\href{run:#1.pdf}{\small\textcolor{red}{pdf}}}%
    \else%
        \index{#2!#1\href{run:#1.pdf}{\tiny\textcolor{red}{pdf}}}%
    \fi%
}%
\newcommand{\EndProcessWords}{}

\begin{document}
\DTLnewdb{DB}%
\DTLnewrow{DB}% 
\DTLnewdbentry{DB}{FileName}{Now good enough}% 
\DTLnewrow{DB}% 
\DTLnewdbentry{DB}{FileName}{Now good enough for you and me}% 

\DTLforeach{DB}{\FileName=FileName}{%
    \section{\FileName}%
    \par\noindent\href{run:\FileName.pdf}{\FileName}%
    \ProcessEachWord{\FileName}%
}%

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You find the rejected entries in the `.ilg` file, which is the log of Makeindex's activities.

Where's the problem? If you look at the entries generated when `\UseSmallInIndex` is undefined, you find them of the form

```
\indexentry{Now!Now good enough\href  {run:Now good enough.pdf}{\relax \fontsize  {5}{6}\selectfont  \leavevmode {\color  {red}pdf}}|hyperpage}{1}
```

and you see that `\tiny` has been substituted by its expansion. The expansion of `\small` gives instead

```
\indexentry{Now!Now good enough\href  {run:Now good enough.pdf}{\relax \fontsize  {9}{11}\selectfont  \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ plus3\p@ minus4\p@ \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ plus2\p@ \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \def \leftmargin \leftmargini \parsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@ \topsep 8\p@ plus2\p@ minus4\p@ \itemsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@ {\leftmargin \leftmargini \topsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus2\p@ \parsep 2\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@ \itemsep \parsep }\belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip \leavevmode {\color  {red}pdf}}|hyperpage}{1}
```

which is where Makindex chokes.

Solution:

```
\newcommand{\ProcessWord}[2][]{%
  \ifdefined\UseSmallInIndex
    \index{#2!#1\href{run:#1.pdf}{\protect\small\protect\textcolor{red}{pdf}}}%
  \else
    \index{#2!#1\href{run:#1.pdf}{\protect\tiny\protect\textcolor{red}{pdf}}}%
  \fi 
}
```

I'd also use `\protected@edef` in the definition of `\ProcessEachWord` for similar reasons.