# Remove page number from index entries

Tags: page-numbering, indexing

My indexed terms are hyperlinks (to external files -- see question listed below), so the page numbers are really not useful information. Hece I would like to be able to remove the page number (and the comma preceding the page number).

The MWEs below produce the image on the left, but I would like it to produce the image on the right:

[image]
[image]

Would be nice if one solution worked with all the packages, but package specific solutions are ok too. I am using `imakeidx` so that would be most helpful to me.

### References:

- This is a follow up to [Index hyperlinks to open a PDF file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51601/index-hyperlinks-to-open-a-pdf-file).
- [List of Indexing Packages - Pros and Cons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51603/list-of-indexing-packages-pros-and-cons)

### Code: `imakeidx`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[columns=1]

\begin{document}
  Test\index{foo}
  \index{bar}
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

### Code: `makeidx`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
  Test\index{foo}
  \index{bar}
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: The second referenced question is not all that useful _yet_, but one can always hope.... :-)

Comment: I have to ask :) .... what is the point of an entry in the index if there is no page number to go with it?

Comment: @cmhughes: That is a good question, so sorry for not making it clearer in the question. This is not a traditional index. The indexed terms are hyperlinks to files so the page numbers only point to the page where I added the file to the index. The _only_ useful part of this document is the index, the body has no value.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I answer this question for two index processors: `makeindex` and `texindy`. 
Both examples use the package `imakeidx` to simplify the compilation.

---

### texindy

With `texindy` you have to compile with the option `shell-escape`.

First of all I set the option `texindy` of the package `imakeidx` to specify the index processor.

```
\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-M mystyle.xdy]
```

The `options` specify what will be passed as an argument to `texindy`. The option `-M mystyle.xdy` means that `texindy` use the style file`mystyle.xdy`.

#### the algorithm

Before I explain the code I want to explain the algorithm which I use.

1. The comma between the index entry and the page number is a simple predefined operator of the `texindy` style. So I can change it by setting them inside the style file.
2. Every page number of the index entry can be surrounded and modified with a command. To suppress the output of the page number, I can use the LaTeX kernel command `\@gobble` which is simply defined as

   ```
   \def\@gobble#1{}
   ```

These modification must be executed after the sorting algorithm of the index processor. So you can't remove the page of `\indexentry`.

#### Now the implementation.

The index processor `texindy` (and also `makeindex`) can't handle LaTeX commands with an `@` symbol, because `@` is a special character for the index processor. So I defined a command equal to `\@gobble`

```
\let\mygobble\@gobble
```

The usage will be explained later. Next I have to manipulate the command `\index` so that every page number of the the command `index` will be modified. Therefore you can use the expansion `|`. For example to print a bold page number you use `\index{foo|textbf}`. The `textbf` is a predefined attribute of the index processor. Instead of `textbf` I use the attribute `gobble`. The command `\index` provided by `imakeidx` has an optional argument so I recommend the macro `\LetLtxMacro` provided by package `letltxmacro` instead of `\let`

```
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|gobble}}
```

Through this redefinition every index command gets the attribute `gobble`. 
This attribute is defined in the style file for the `texindy` run:

```
(define-attributes (("gobble" "default")))
(markup-locref  :open "\mygobble{" :close "}" :attr "gobble")
(markup-locclass-list :open "" :sep "")
```

In the first line I define a new attribute. In the second line I say what the attribute should do. Here the command `\mygobble` is used. The third line defines the separator to be empty `""`.

Side note: Comments in a `texindy` style file are introduced with a `;`.

Altogether we get the following example:

```
%% !TEX program  = pdflatex --shell-escape
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-M mystyle.xdy]
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\let\mygobble\@gobble
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|gobble}} 
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.xdy}
;;; xindy style file
(define-attributes (("gobble" "default")))
(markup-locref  :open "\mygobble{" :close "}" :attr "gobble")
(markup-locclass-list :open "" :sep "")
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
Test\index{foo}
\index{bar}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

---

### makeindex

In relation to `makeindex` here are the options for the package `imakeidx`

```
\makeindex[program=makeindex,options=-s mystyle.ist]
```

The option `options` must be set to `-s mystyle.ist` because in this way you pass a style file to the index processor `makeindex`.

`makeindex` works with the same algorithm. So the lines are almost identical

```
\let\mygobble\@gobble
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|mygobble}}
```

Unlike `texindy`, `makeindex` doesn't work with attributes. The command `mygobble` without backslash will be passed as an argument of `\index` to the processor. The processor will write `\mygobble{\thepage}`.

The separator must be redefined inside a style file.

```
quote '+'
delim_0 " "
delim_1 " "
delim_2 " "
delim_n " "
```

`delim_0` etc. are the separator of the different levels.

Side note: Comments in a `makeindex` style file are introduced with a the same as in LaTeX the `%`.

So we get the following example with `makeindex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=makeindex,options=-s mystyle.ist]
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\let\mygobble\@gobble
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|mygobble}} 
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.ist}
quote '+'
delim_0 " "
delim_1 " "
delim_2 " "
delim_n " "
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
Test\index{foo}
\index{bar}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

---

### hyperref support

Remember to load `imakeidx` before `hyperref`.

In combination with `hyperref` the approach with `makeindex` doesn't need any special handling. If you use `texindy` in combination with hyperref you have to change the style file `*.xdy` in the following way:

```
(markup-locclass-list :open "" :sep "")
(markup-range :sep "")
```

In the document body you must change the printing of the index as follows to gobble the page numbers:

```
\begingroup
\def\hyperpage#1{}
\printindex
\endgroup
```

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-M mystyle.xdy]
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.xdy}
;;; xindy style file
(markup-locclass-list :open "" :sep "")
(markup-range :sep "")
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
Test\index{foo}
\index{bar}

\begingroup
\def\hyperpage#1{}
\printindex
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: One side remark: In `makeindex` style files the comment sign is the same like in (La)TeX, so one could use there the `filecontents` environment (without the star) as well.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Did you notice the section about `hyperref`?

Comment: @ Marco Daniel This code `\printindex[main] \printindex[author] \begingroup \def\hyperpage#1{} \printindex \endgroup` work perfect with multiple Indexes too. I wanted one extra "index" without page numbers. Thanks

Comment: @Marco Daniel, I have some quite long index entries, which split along several lines and are left aligned (I guess by default). Is there a way to get justified text using your implementation?