# Generate only the index, no main body text

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I would like to discard the entire document and have *only* the index remaining.

Note:

- This is a follow up to an earlier question of mine [Remove page number from index entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/remove-page-number-from-index-entries).
- This document is an index of hyper linked files, so the content is not useful.

My naive attempt below does not produce any output. I want Page 2 of the document that gets generated if the `\usebox{\DiscardBox}` line is un-commented, but not Page 1.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[columns=1]

\newsavebox{\DiscardBox}

\begin{document}
  \savebox{\DiscardBox}{%
    Test\index{foo}
    Testing\index{bar}
  }%
  %\usebox{\DiscardBox}

  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Index writing is performed at `\shipout` time, so if nothing is shipped out no index is produced.

Comment: why not just have a new document which inputs the `.ind` file of the first (and does nothing else)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: WOW!! That is pure genius... Never occurred to me.  Seems to work fine. What do I need to do get only a one column index?  Using just `\input{<file>.ind}` produces a two column output.

Comment: look in chat:-)

Comment: Are you talking visually remove everything but the index? That is, if you have a document of 10 pages with 1 page dedicated to the index, then you can delete pages 1-9 and only be left with "page 10"?

Comment: @Werner: Yes that is the desired result. Are you thinking of something like `pdfpages` to create a new doc with the relevant pages?  That might also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`imakeidx` sets the number of columns with `\imki@columns`; so you can simply build another document with the following format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\imki@columns{1}
\def\indexname{External index}
\makeatother
\input{mainfile.ind}

\end{document}
```

leaving to the class the rest.

Answer (score 6):

Just have a new document which inputs the `.ind` file of the first (and does nothing else) .