# How to redefine a final generated indexitem in imakeidx/splitindex

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I want to define `\index[table]{#1}` to hold several arguments: `\index[table]{{#1}{#2}}` and build a table row with it, using the `splitindex`.

How can I do this?

Comment: why complicate the makindex and change the structure of \item? just write \index{{aa}{bb}} and then define your final generated indexitem entry to take two arguments and make a table row

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I suspect you're referring to e.g. `imki@indexitem` for `imakeidx`?

Comment: not specifically but perhaps (not looked at imakeidx for a long while) just the general principle that makeindex writes a sorted list of commands but the definition of those commands is entirely under the control of macro definitions in latex so all you need to do is get makeindex to write stuff in the correct order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `imakeidx` nor with `\item`. Just define a new index style. With `imakeidx` it's just simpler to manage the whole thing.

### File `ind10.ist`

Save this file in the same directory as your LaTeX file

```
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\n\\begin{longtable}{lll}\\mygobble"
postamble "\n\\end{longtable}\n\\end{theindex}\n"
item_0 "\\\\\n\\mymacro"
delim_0 "&"
```

### Test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[options=-s ind10,columns=1]

\newcommand{\mymacro}[2]{#1&#2}
\newcommand{\mygobble}[1]{}% for gobbling the first \\

\begin{document}

abc\index{{aa}{bb}}\index{{ddd}{eeeeeeeee}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

### Resulting `.ind` file

```
\begin{theindex}
\begin{longtable}{lll}\mygobble\\
\mymacro{aa}{bb}&1\\
\mymacro{ddd}{eeeeeeeee}&1
\end{longtable}
\end{theindex}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: One small additional question - how to supress the page numbering for the index? I'll accept your question tomorrow as I'm currently not at a PC with TeX on it - and I want to make sure that this works for my case. :-)

Comment: Are you meaning the page number in the index entries? Then you don't want an index, but a glossary. The `glossaries` package is surely better for this.

Comment: **I believe I found it at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/remove-page-number-from-index-entries**

Comment: @1010011010 You could also “silence” the final column, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/easiest-way-to-delete-a-column which might be easier in this case.

Comment: While I still have the oppertunity to ask - I already have a different style file for another index - is this going to pose a problem?

Comment: @1010011010 No, when you pass `options=-s <name>.ist` to an index, it's not inherited by other indices. If you don't pass the `-s` option, the default style is used.