# Normalized / sorted index entries with Xindy

Tags: xindy

I'm working on a an sorted name register produced by an external program with dozens of entries of one surname. To find the main pages easier I try to colorize it and played with different text styles (*italic*, **bold**).
Xindy seems to be the right solution for this job (see MWE, the first output line is the test result, the second line is the target):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myindex.xdy}
  ;;; xindy style file
  (define-attributes ("gobble" "red" "green") )

  (markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill" :close "" :sep ", ")
  (markup-locref :open "\mygobble{" :close "}" :attr "gobble" )
  (markup-locref :open "\myred{" :close "}" :attr "red" )
  (markup-locref :open "\color{green}{" :close "}\color{black}" :attr "green" )
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
  \let\mygobble\@gobble
\makeatother

\def\myred#1{\color{red}#1\color{black}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
  \noindent  
  \begingroup
    {\large\textbf{Test}\normalsize} \newline
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \printindex
  \endgroup

  \vspace{1cm} \noindent 
  {\large\textbf{Target}\normalsize} \newline \newline
  1. Entry ...................... % 
    2, \textbf{3}, {\color{green}4}, \textit{5}, {\color{red}6--8}

  \index{1. Entry|gobble}   
  \newpage Page 2. \index{1. Entry} \index{1. Entry|red}
  \newpage Page 3. \index{1. Entry|textbf}
  \newpage Page 4. \index{1. Entry|green}
  \newpage Page 5. \index{1. Entry|textit}
  \newpage Page 6. \index{1. Entry|red}
  \newpage Page 7. \index{1. Entry|red}
  \newpage Page 8. \index{1. Entry|red}

\end{document}
```

As we've learned from the famous Latex Companion, 2nd edit., Xindy greps always the first entry as a reference for all subsequent entries. I created a blind page only with the (in reality quite complex) main indices and modified the location reference to gobble the page number (see [Remove page number from index entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/remove-page-number-from-index-entries)).

I use full TeXLive 2015, compilation with:

pdflatex.exe myindex.tex
xindy -M texindy -M myindex -C utf8 -L german-duden myindex.idx
pdflatex.exe myindex.tex

Result is:

- Gobbling works (no page number), but creates an extra comma (logical, but unwanted!)
- Xindy direct colored attributes (green) placed at line end
- Xindy indirect colored attributes (red) placed in between
- Page number sorting depends on attribute type
- Some separators are missing

How can Xindy's configuration file(s) be changed, that:

1. Entries forced with a defined layout, but without tricks like
   gobbled page numbers?
2. Sorting of pages is independent from attributes?
3. All separators placed as expected?