# Custom list of floats combining makeindex and bibliography features

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, makeindex

For my document, I will have to print extracts of interviews I've conducted. 
I would like to display a list of those interviews, the same way we display a bibliography (with custom fields: date, location, people, etc.). I would love to have this list working as an index, with references for pages where the extracts are displayed.

Ideally, it would look like that :
[image]

and it would be used with a normal `\ref` :

```
\ref{itw:Louis1}
```

would display the tag [14-07-89, Capet] right here, and an environment :

```
\begin{interview}
    \interviewref{itw:Louis1}

     Oca: So, what did you catch yesterday ?

     Louis: Oh, not that much.
\end{interview}
```

would display extract of interview AND add the current page on the list of interviews at the correct place. The data might be on a .bib file and then displayed in a custom way, or maybe in some custom containers :

```
\begin{listofinterviews}
    \begin{interview}
        \label{itw:Louis1}
        \name[Capet]{Louis-Auguste \textsc{Capet}, aka Louis XVI of France, King\\}
        \date{14-07-1789}
    \end{interview}
\end{listofinterviews}
```

Note : some interviews will not have any extract and I would like to display them, but with no `\dotfill` nor numbers.

I'm okay doing all the reference logic by myself. My problem is on the display of the list.

---

I see two starting points :

1. Using an index with `imakeidx` and make `\interviewref` call `\index{\ref{#1}}`.

   But for this option I have two problems:

   - Displaying the data between every entry
   - Force the index to print the entry even if it is never called. (For this problem, I think I can solve it with [this technique](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/remove-page-number-from-index-entries), but if you know how to force the display of an entry like `\nocite` does it with bibliography, I'd love to know it.)
2. Using a bibliography tool, with a custom field that would work like/with and index, or with some bibliography tools that provide a link from the bibliography page to the citation. (But I could not find correct keywords with the search engine, everyone tries to display the page numbers on BibTeX.) I don't think this approach could work.

So, does anyone would know:

1. How to add an entry description after index entries.
2. Add a reverse link on a bibliography list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally \label and \ref only do counters.  Admittedly they can be used for other thing (like pgfplots legends), but all you really need is to write LaTeX code to the aux file, which is read at \begin{document}.  The first step is to inspect an existing aux file and see what sort of stuff is being stored there.

Comment: I hoped there was a way to avoid that since I am not very aware of how .aux files work. But I'll have a look, thanks.