# Modifying a Makeindex Algorithm to Remove Page Numbers on a Selective Basis Only

Tags: macros, page-numbering, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

I have extracted the following code from an answer in [Remove page number from index entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/remove-page-number-from-index-entries/52150#52150)

which removes the page number from each index entry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[program=makeindex,options=-s mystyle.ist]

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\let\mygobble\@gobble
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|mygobble}} 
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.ist}
quote '+'
delim_0 " "
delim_1 " "
delim_2 " "
delim_n " "
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\LARGE

Test\index{foo}
\index{bar}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the index output:

[image]

I thought, perhaps, there might be a way to modify the above code so that the page number might be "gobbled" on a selective basis instead of globally; more specifically, I attempted to define an index command, say, `\index1` that would remove the page number if used---and, if using `\index`, the page number would be retained.

However, I was unsuccessful in my various attempts.

QUESTION: If possible, how might one modify the above code so that the entry page number may be removed on a selective (and not global) basis?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use     `\newcommand{\indexi}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|mygobble}}` (numbers are not allowed in commands names)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[program=makeindex,options=-s mystyle.ist]

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\let\mygobble\@gobble
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\newcommand{\indexi}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|mygobble}} % changed <<<<<<<<
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.ist}
    quote '+'
    delim_0 " "
    delim_1 " "
    delim_2 " "
    delim_n " "
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \LARGE
    
    Test\indexi{foo}  % no page number
    \index{bar}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer.

Comment: @mlchristians You did all the work :-)

Comment: Thank you again for the assistance you have given me on this, and other problems as well.