# Abbreviate only middle names in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, acronyms

I know of the option `firstinits=true` to abbreviate the first and all middle names in biblatex. What I would like to achieve is to only abbreviate the middle names. So e.g. `author = {Smith, John Ethan Jacob}` should be printed as `Smith, John E. J.`

Please see the MWE based on the answer of Jonathan from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126061/bibliography-with-biblatex-do-not-abbreviate-first-given-first-name-and-abbre) post at the end of this question. I get the following output:

> [SD95] Smith, John E. J./Doe, Jain L. Some book title. A Publisher, 1995.

But what I would like to see as output is:

> [SD95] Smith, John E. J. ; Doe, Jain L: Some book title. A Publisher, 1995.

The `;` between the author names and the `:` between the author names and the book title are specific to the bib style (custom made) I use. But the solution below doesn't respect this custom style. Any idea how to achieve the desired abbreviation, but don't loose the bib style?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=din, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@BOOK{SD1995,
  author = {Smith, John Ethan Jacob and Doe, Jain Lauren},
  title = {Some book title},
  year = {1995},
  publisher = {A Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\bibnamedelima{ }%
\def\bibnamedelimb{ }%
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \ifblank{#5}{}{#5\addspace}% prefix if applicable
  #1% last name
  \edef\firstname{#3}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{\addcomma\addspace\expandafter\first{\firstname}}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
   {\addslash}{}%
}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifblank{#5}{}{#5\addspace}% prefix if applicable
  #1% last name
  \edef\firstname{#3}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{\addcomma\addspace\expandafter\first{\firstname}}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
   {\addslash}{}%
}

\makeatletter
\def\@empty{}
\def\first#1{\expandafter\@first#1 \@nil}
\def\@first#1 #2\@nil{#1\addspace%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else\@initials#2\@nil\fi}
\def\initials#1{\expandafter\@initials#1 \@nil}
\def\@initials#1 #2\@nil{%
  \initial{#1}%
  \def\NextName{#2}%
  \ifx\@empty\NextName\relax%
  \else\@initials#2\@nil\fi}
\def\initial#1{\expandafter\@initial#1\@nil}
\def\@initial#1#2\@nil{#1.\addspace}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\null
\vfill

How the citation look like: \cite{SD1995}

\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Edit**
Please look [here](https://github.com/domhardt/BibLaTeX-DIN1505) for the din style I'm using in the MWE. With this style I get two white spaces between the first author and the separating `;`, when I use the modification by Andrew Swann. Without the modification there is only one white space. I'm now looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: is [Bibliography with BibLaTeX: Do not abbreviate first given (first) name and abbreviate all further given names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126061) helpful?

Comment: @cmhughes Nearly, but it changes the styles of my bibstyle. So for example in the style the last names are in small caps and the delimiter between multiple authors is a ' ; ' not '/'. Do you know how to change it?

Comment: @cmhughes And if the last name of the authors list is one with a middle name the ':' between its name and the title of the book is missing. For Example: `Smith, John: The handbook of` but `Smith, John E. The handbook of`

Comment: Please provide a MWE.

Comment: @musicman I added the MWE in my initial post. I hope it is clear what I mean, even without my custom bib style.

Comment: Why do you want to abbreviate parts of names in a bibliography? The names in the bibliography should be _identical_ to the names in the original source.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen In most of the cases only the last name is given and both the first and middle names are abbreviated or the first and last name is given and the middle names are abbreviated. Would you type them identically to the source even if this leads to cases where you have two sources of the same author (different journal and guidelines) and in one you abbreviate the first name and in the other don't just because it is identically copied from the source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is something less invasive than the solution you have tried.  It relies on adjusting the macro `\mkbibnamegiven` which is called to format the first and middle names rather than completely rewriting the name format:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@BOOK{SD1995,
  author = {Smith, John Ethan Jacob and Doe, Jain Lauren},
  title = {Some book title},
  year = {1995},
  publisher = {A Publisher}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\edef\firstname{#1}\expandafter\first{\firstname}}

\def\bibnamedelima{ }%
\def\bibnamedelimb{ }%

\makeatletter
\def\@empty{}
\def\first#1{\expandafter\@first#1 \@nil}
\def\@first#1 #2\@nil{#1\addspace%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else\@initials#2\@nil\fi}
\def\initials#1{\expandafter\@initials#1 \@nil}
\def\@initials#1 #2\@nil{%
  \initial{#1}%
  \def\NextName{#2}%
  \ifx\@empty\NextName\relax%
  \else\bibinitdelim \@initials#2\@nil\fi}
\def\initial#1{\expandafter\@initial#1\@nil}
\def\@initial#1#2\@nil{#1\bibinitperiod}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
How the citations appear: \cite{SD1995}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

*Update* with the `din` style you point to in your update you should add

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}}
```

to your preamble.  The `din` style contains the definition

```
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\mbox{ }\addspace\addsemicolon\addspace}
```

which adds a single space before the semicolon.  Another way to get a single space would be

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addspace;\addspace}}
```

Comment: Thank you, nearly perfect. One little thing between the abbreviated `J.` (Jacob) of the first author and the separating `;` I have now two white spaces (without the modification there is only one). It does not happen in your solution with the alphabetic style, because there the separator is the word `and`. Do you have an idea why this happen or how I can provide my custom style here so it becomes clear what I'm talking about ;)

Comment: You can add your custom style to your question.  The most obvious question is how are you adding spaces and punctuation? In particular do you use biblatex's macros such as `\addspace` etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The style I'm using is basically [this](https://github.com/domhardt/BibLaTeX-DIN1505) one (just modified it a little) The problem with the `;` can be reproduced with the original style from domhardt, but I don't know where to look for it. I updated my original post with this style and a link to the github rep.

Comment: Thanks for the update. With the modification the white space is gone completely so now it's `J.; Doe`. What I would like to have is a single white space before and after the semicolon like `J. ; Doe`. I tried `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addspace\addsemicolon\addspace}}` so without the `mbox{}` of the original style but it didn't work.

Comment: I think there is only one space there - anyway I have added another way to get a space.

Comment: Note that this answer is now obsolete, you should redefine mkbibnamegiven and note the mkbibnamefirst which is obsolote. But it works well :
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\edef\firstname{#1}\expandafter\first{\firstname}}

Comment: @NilsBeaussé Many thanks.  Code updated.