# Parsing and programming in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, pgfkeys, parsing

Background: I'be been reading the PGF manual (keys section) and today the TeX Book just arrived in the mail and just started reading chapter 7 (How TeX reads what you type) -- feeling like Mickey Mouse in "The Sorcerers Apprentice".

I want (but this is **not** the question) to do a routine that does something like that:

```
   input:   a,b ; c,d ; e,f.
   output:  a\nodepart{b} && c\nodepart{d} && e\nodepart{f}\\
```

My idea was to use the PGF parser to read the input. If I were using the languages I know (old Basic, Python, Maple script) I would save intermediary results in a variable but for what I understood so far LaTeX/TeX/ and TikZ/PGF do not work in this way. There is no string manipulation routines. I know we can store stuff into pgf keys. Before you stop reading I better ask my questions:

1. Are there any examples of (LaTeX/TeX/ and TikZ/PGF) code that reads some input of **variable lenght** possibly more than ten and spits some other code?
2. With the example above in mind, which references should I read to be able to implement the routine in an efficient way?

Post-script:

1. Reading the suggested tags, I just learn about the LaTeX parse package, will check it also.
2. @egreg: The ultimate goal will be to define a bimatrix environment in TikZ to display two-player games in normal form. The idea is to create outputs similar to this http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/stengel/bimatrixgame/example.pdf but with the **intuitive and human-like language** we see in TikZ constructs.

Comment: In [How do I split a string?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12810) you have other pointers

Comment: @JLDiaz: Thanks! Please correct me if I am wrong. The accepted answer to the question you mentioned works only if the input has a fixed number of parts but the second answer does the job, right?

Comment: Yes, the second one uses some low-level tricks to adapt itself to an arbitrary number of words. You can have fun trying to understand this solution armed with your new book of spells :-)

Comment: It's important to know *where* and *how* you want to use this. Can you make an example?

Comment: You may be able to use any of the options listed in [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159118/5764)

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I hope my edit in the question addresses your comment.

Comment: You can use a recursive macro definition to do the transformation you show very simply in pure TeX, though I don't know if that helps with your real question. (Let me know if you would be interested in seeing this as an answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an adaptation of the [second answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12819/12571) of the question [How do I split a string?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/how-do-i-split-a-string) to your problem. It is not exactly what you want, but it can help to get you on the way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\makeatletter
\def\processArg#1,#2{%
  #1 nodepart #2
}
\def\myutil@empty{}
\def\severalparts#1;#2\@nil{%
 \def\NextArg{#2}%
 \processArg#1%
 \ifx\myutil@empty\NextArg
     \let\next\@gobble
 \else XX
 \fi
 \next#2\@nil
}%
\def\ProcessString#1{%
   \let\next\severalparts
   \next#1;\@nil %
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ProcessString{a,b;c,d;e,f}
\end{document}
```

This the pdf output:

[image: Result]

Comment: @SergioParreiras And, as Mickey the sorcercer learned the hard way, always remember to include a termination condition in your loops. Otherwise, infinite expansion will lead to overflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to slightly change the input format a simpler solution is to use `\foreach`:

[image]

### Notes:

- This may or may not work for you depending on your particular application.
- The intermediate step using an `\edef` allows this to be used with a string, or a macro defined string. See [TikZ \foreach loop with macro-defined list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/tikz-foreach-loop-with-macro-defined-list) for more details.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\ProcessString}[1]{%
    \edef\StringToProcess{#1}%
    \foreach \x/\y in \StringToProcess {%
        \x\ nodepart \{\y\} XX
    }%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyStrings}{x/y,w/u,1/2}%

\begin{document}
\ProcessString{a/b,c/d,e/f}

\bigskip
\ProcessString{\MyStrings}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\StringToProcess` intermediate variable? You can use `\foreach ... in {#1}`. There are unknown caveats?

Comment: @JLDiaz: The intermediate step is useful as you can use it with a direct string, or a string defined via a macro. See updated solution.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Neat! But is there a way we can have the characters `\ ` and `{` in the output? That is: `a\nodepart{b}` instead of `a nodepart b`?

Comment: @SergioParreiras: Sure, just add a `\{` and `\}`. Have updated solution. However, as I warned in the solution, this may or may not work for you depending on the actual application.

Comment: @Sergio I haven't tested, but try saying `\string\nodepart` or `\cs{nodepart}` in place of the plain `nodepart`.