# print document author last name, firstname with abntex

Tags: abnt

Hi I'm editing a sty document and I am trying to get print the author's name (that was declared in the preamble like this

```
\titulo{Title}
\autor{First mid. last name}
```

and I am using the command \imprimirautor to print the author's name like it is declared in the preamble. but how do I print it in the format of last name, first name?

this is the portion of the sty that I am trying to get this to work

```
\newcommand{\insereFichaCatalografica}{ 
 \begin{fichacatalografica}%\color{blue}

 \IfFileExists{metadados/FichaC.pdf}
    {\includepdf[pages=-]{metadados/FichaC}}
    {
    \vspace*{\fill}                 % Posição vertical
    %\hrule                         % Linha horizontal
    \begin{center}
        Ficha catalográfica elaborada automaticamente com os dados fornecidos \\
        pelo(a) autor(a) através do Módulo de Biblioteca do \\
        Sistema GURI (Gestão Unificada de Recursos Institucionais) . 

    \end{center}
    \vspace{-15 mm}
    \begin{center}                  % Minipage Centralizado
    \begin{minipage}[c]{10cm}       % Largura

    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}

    \vspace{0cm}
    \fbox{
    \begin{center}                  % Minipage Centralizado
    \begin{minipage}[c]{12.5cm}     % Largura

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% here is suposed to be last name, first name %%%%%%%%%%%
   \imprimirautor 

    \hspace{0.5cm} \imprimirtitulo  / \imprimirautor. --
    \imprimirlocal, \imprimirdata-

    \hspace{0.5cm} \pageref{LastPage} p. : il. (algumas color.) ; 30 cm.\\

    \hspace{0.5cm} 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\imprimirorientador}{}}
            {\imprimirorientadoraRotulo~\imprimirorientadora}
            {\imprimirorientadorRotulo~\imprimirorientador}
    \\

    \hspace{5mm}
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\imprimirtipotrabalho~--~\imprimirinstituicao,
    \imprimirdata.}\\

      \hspace{5mm}
       \begin{minipage}{.80\textwidth}
            1. \PalavraschaveTexto

            I.  \ifthenelse{\equal{\imprimirorientador}{}}
            {\imprimirorientadoraRotulo~\imprimirorientadora}
            {\imprimirorientadorRotulo~\imprimirorientador}.

           II. \imprimirinstituicao

          III. \imprimirCurso

           IV. \imprimirtitulo\\ 


      \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    }
    %\hrule
 }
 \end{fichacatalografica}
}
```

Comment: I guess you could just write down the author's name (how many times do you use it, anyway?). It would save you all the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [How do I split a string?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/how-do-i-split-a-string) this works, and might be what you're looking for:

```
\def\testnameswap#1{\nameswap#1\relax}
\def\nameswap#1 #2\relax{#2, #1}
\testnameswap{Firstname Lastname}
```