# Splitting string and retrieving part of it

Tags: strings, parsing

I would like to take a string in Beamer and retrieve part of it. The solution at [How do I split a string?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/how-do-i-split-a-string) gets me very close to what I want; but using it as example, i.e. if the string is:

```
\def\MyTeXKnowledge{Not good enough}
```

How can I retrieve an arbitrary word of this string, e.g. `good`? The output of the mentioned solution gives `(Not)(good)(enough)`.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `listofitems` package is made to parse lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\MyTeXKnowledge{Not good enough}
\begin{document}
\setsepchar{ }
\readlist\mylist\MyTeXKnowledge
Second item is: \mylist[2]

The list has \mylistlen{} items.

The last item is: \mylist[-1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steven, but `\usepackage{listofitems}` is not available for me; maybe because I am using: `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)` `kpathsea version 6.1.1`. Unfortunately, I cannot update it by myself... However, I will mark your reply as solution, since it is very concise

Comment: @RigelF.doC. You can obtain the sources at https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems.  If you are unable to install it in your system, merely placing the files `listofitems.tex` and `listofitems.sty` in your working directory will suffice.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot @Steven!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article} % or any other

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getchunk}{smm}
 {% #1 = optional * (when a command is used for #2
  % #2 = string
  % #3 = item number
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } #2
   }
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #2 }
   }
  \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\MyTeXKnowledge}{Not good enough}

\begin{document}

\getchunk*{\MyTeXKnowledge}{2}

\getchunk{Not good enough}{3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

We might add a check that there are enough chunks.

```
\documentclass{article} % or any other

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getchunk}{smm}
 {% #1 = optional * (when a command is used for #2
  % #2 = string
  % #3 = item number
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \rigel_getchunk:Vn  #2 { #3 }
   }
   {
    \rigel_getchunk:nn  { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \rigel_getchunk:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \int_compare:nTF { #2 > \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq }
   {
    ??? \ERROR
   }
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \rigel_getchunk:nn { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\MyTeXKnowledge}{Not good enough}

\begin{document}

\getchunk*{\MyTeXKnowledge}{2}

\getchunk{Not good enough}{3}

\getchunk*{\MyTeXKnowledge}{100}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ???\ERROR
```

would be raised.

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg, but `\ExplSyntaxOn` is not available for me; maybe because I am using:

`pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)`
`kpathsea version 6.1.1`

Unfortunately, I cannot update it by myself...

Comment: @RigelF.doC. Using an 11-year-old release? Do the sysadmins still use teleprinters or did they start to use modern devices such as green phosphor terminals?